# Keycloak SSO Session Max = 0?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

It is possible to invalidate the Keycloak SSO session when a user closes their browser/tab?

According to the [docs](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/sessions/timeouts.html) I should be able to do this by setting the `SSO Session Idle` and the `SSO Session Max` to `0`.

When setting it to `0` though, I cannot save the settings. What am I misunderstanding here? And is it achievable to log the user out when she closes her browser/tab?

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak cannot terminate the server-side session on browser close, since it does not know that the browser has closed. But since your SSO cookie is a session cookie, your browser will remove the cookie on browser close. Without that cookie you will have to relogin when hooking up your browser again.
Just make sure you did not enable the "Remember Me" feature at `Realm settings -> Login`.

However, there is no support for this when closing a tab, as far as I know.

Comment: I guess that is the problem. The SSO cookie is not a session cookie. It has an expiry of 10 hours. I would like to set the expiry to 0, so it is handled as a session cookie.

Comment: I am not sure which cookie you are referring to. KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY and AUTH_SESSION_ID are both session cookies unless you enable "remember me".
Are you referring to KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookie?
What would be the purpose of setting the lifetime to 0? With this you would basically disable SSO.